# How to search for recurrent events created by other user

Tags: google-calendar-api

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

By specifying 'primary' as the calendar ID, I got the recurrence event I created.
However, recurrence events created by others will not be acquired.

By inserting my e-mail address in the 'q' parameter, I got them but got no events where attendees does not exist.

Is there a way to get both of these at the same time?
I am very fortunate to be able to help by someone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Events: list documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#top_of_page), use the [try it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) section to get the event from a specific user. Then it will return the events with the specified parameters. See the sample response below:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": etag,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "items": [
    events Resource
  ]
}
```

You must be able to get your needed information like the `creator`, `organizer` and `attendees`.

[image]

The value of each parameters was discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#parameters).

This is the sample response after you successfully get a 200 response code:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "status": string,
  "htmlLink": string,
  "created": datetime,
  "updated": datetime,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  "colorId": string,
  "creator": {
    "id": string,
    "email": string,
    "displayName": string,
    "self": boolean
  },
  "organizer": {
    "id": string,
    "email": string,
    "displayName": string,
    "self": boolean
  },
  "start": {
    "date": date,
    "dateTime": datetime,
    "timeZone": string
  },
  "end": {
    "date": date,
    "dateTime": datetime,
    "timeZone": string
  },
  "endTimeUnspecified": boolean,
  "recurrence": [
    string
  ],
  "recurringEventId": string,
  "originalStartTime": {
    "date": date,
    "dateTime": datetime,
    "timeZone": string
  },
  "transparency": string,
  "visibility": string,
  "iCalUID": string,
  "sequence": integer,
  "attendees": [
    {
      "id": string,
      "email": string,
      "displayName": string,
      "organizer": boolean,
      "self": boolean,
      "resource": boolean,
      "optional": boolean,
      "responseStatus": string,
      "comment": string,
      "additionalGuests": integer
    }
  ],
  "attendeesOmitted": boolean,
  "extendedProperties": {
    "private": {
      (key): string
    },
    "shared": {
      (key): string
    }
  },
  "hangoutLink": string,
  "gadget": {
    "type": string,
    "title": string,
    "link": string,
    "iconLink": string,
    "width": integer,
    "height": integer,
    "display": string,
    "preferences": {
      (key): string
    }
  },
  "anyoneCanAddSelf": boolean,
  "guestsCanInviteOthers": boolean,
  "guestsCanModify": boolean,
  "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": boolean,
  "privateCopy": boolean,
  "locked": boolean,
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": boolean,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "method": string,
        "minutes": integer
      }
    ]
  },
  "source": {
    "url": string,
    "title": string
  },
  "attachments": [
    {
      "fileUrl": string,
      "title": string,
      "mimeType": string,
      "iconLink": string,
      "fileId": string
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
But my problem is that I do not know what this parameter can improve by solving it.
I tried specifying attendees for the 'q' parameter, but then it will make it impossible to have an attendees schedule.
Even if you do not specify anything for 'q', you can get the Events you created (there are also attendees).

Is there no way to get both of them at once?